# How can we use advanced date filter(SYSDATE) in Source while reading the data in informatica iics?

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud, informatica-data-integration-hub, iics, iics-di

I am unable to use advanced filters in the source of Informatica before reading the data. I want to compare a field with SYSDATE so I am going to advanced filters in Source there is SYSDATE a system variable predefined in Informatica so I am equating tablename.field=SYSDATE or tablename.field=$$SYSDATE or tablename.field=$$SYSDATE by none of them is working. Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omhSI.png) of Source filter definition.

Please help how can I compare field with SYSDATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a parameter, e.g. SYSDATE and then refer to parameter value by putting $$SYSDATE in the filter - almost like you do, but there has to be a parameter declared and value defined for this parameter. Otherwise this is just a comparison to string SYSDATE, not the desired date value.